# What happens when you change an array connected to a mapping in solidity?

Tags: solidity

I have a mapping

```
mapping(address => BetByUser[]) betsByAddress;
```

What happens when I change an object in BetByUser array, or push something to the array? Will it also change the mapping?

Comment: What do you mean by changing the mapping? After pushing into the array, or changing the object, it will stay changed. If you read from the mapping later, you will get your updated data.

Comment: My BetByUser array is not changing... Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visualize this mapping initially like this

```
" "-------->[]  // its empty
```

When I push something using an address then it becomes this

```
"address1"-------->["pushedItem"]
```

If I push more items then

```
"address1"-------->["pushedItem","pushedItem2"]
```

If I add an item using different address then it will look like this:

```
"address1"-------->["pushedItem","pushedItem2"]
"address2"-------->["pushedItem3"]
```

> Will it also change the mapping?

No, it only adds another item in the array for the specific address.
Will it create a new mapping? No it won't.

Comment: Hey I'm sorry, but this doesn't my badly formulated question. When I push new items to my BetByUser array it doesn't seem to change the array. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: I answered your other question take a look at it. You did a -15 reputation on me. :(

Comment: holy moly sorry...